# How to convert a JSON request body to SOAP Request Body in SpringBoot?

Tags: json, spring-boot, soap, microservices

**Problem Statement:**

I have a use case where I have to convert a JSON request body to SOAP request body so that I can make a call to a legacy micro service in Spring Boot. I know it is super tough but how can I achieve it using any third party maven dependency ?. Any genius answer would be of great help here.

**Conditions:**

1. Don't have any WSDL.
2. I only have the JSON request body.

Comment: one way is to convert json to XML and apply xslt to convert in your XML file.

Comment: How did you solve it?